# How to get a 'hanging note' animation for iPad?

Tags: ipad, animation, tableview

I need to get the animation of a note being stuck on a board for an iPad app that I am doing!

I am using a UITableView for this.

It should have a tilt so that it looks like it has been stuck up on the board.

I liked the Evernote app's notebooks tab design and I am trying something similar.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too vague. You're going to need to do some homework.

Start with [Getting Started with Graphics and Animation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Graphics_iPhone/) (and don't ignore the other guides it tells you to read). Continue with [Core Animation Programming Guide,](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) give [Core Animation Cookbook](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_Cookbook/Introduction/Introduction.html) a read for some ideas, then ask specific, pointed questions when you're ready.